# Using wsadmin to deploy war to a WebSphere 7.0

Tags: websphere, pipeline, jython, cicd

I'm using a client Docker container WAS8.5 (In a Gitlab Pipeline) trying to deploy to a WAS (standalone) 7.0. However, there is a problem because the wsadmin.sh 8.5 can't interact with a WAS7.

Is there an older wsadmin.sh 7?

[image]

Comment: There is a V7.0 wsadmin.sh included in the V7.0 install but V7.0 is well past the end of support https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/end-support-websphere-v70-v80-and-java-6-websphere-v85-april-2018 so I wouldn't expect you'll find a pre-built container image these days.

Comment: where is it? Because it's not in /opt/IBM/WebShpere/AppServer/bin

Comment: Hmm..maybe there's an install type I'm not considering .. I'd expected wsasdmin.sh to be in your install 'bin' directory.

Comment: It is always there, additional copy will be in %PROFILE_ROOT%\bin, If you dont have it your installation is broken. But nevertheless you should update to newer version as v7 is very old and out of support, and even better if you will be migrating go to WebSphere Liberty/Open Liberty, as it is much better fit for containers and pipelines than traditional WAS.